# How to execute a function if define in C++

Tags: c++11

Is there any way to do this

main.cpp

```
#DEFINE DEBUG
int main(){}
```

header.h

```
#ifdef DEBUG
Welcome()
#endif  
void Welcome(){
     std::cout<<"Welcome To Debug" <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not quite - translation units (aka .cpp files) are completely independent and won't share `#define`s.  However you could add `-DDEBUG` when building.

Comment: Also note that if you want to tie this `#define` to your build type, your compiler probably *already* defines `NDEBUG` in Release builds.

Comment: ^^^^ Yeah. You can do something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2RHEMmIOsWiMqnn9 (and https://wandbox.org/permlink/TpFjnBInGfkNx6k6 ), if that's what you meant.